# unable to add menu in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

```
    $page_title = "PushBIZ.IN";
    $menu_title = "PushBIZ.IN";
    $capability = 'activate_plugins';
    $menu_slug  = "pushbiz";
    $function   = "PushBIZIN_first";

    add_menu_page( __('Getting Started'), $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, array($this, $function), plugins_url( WPPUSH_APPNAME.'/assets/images/app20x20.png' ) ); 
    add_submenu_page( $menu_slug, __('BIZ Message'), __('BIZ Message'), $capability, 'BIZMessage', array($this, 'BIZ_Message') );   
    add_submenu_page( $menu_slug, __('Business Analyst'), __('Business Analyst'), $capability, 'businessanalyst', array($this, 'business_analyst') );
    add_submenu_page( $menu_slug, __('BIZ Interests'), __('BIZ Interests'), $capability, 'BIZinterests', array($this, 'BIZ_interests') );
```

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in C:\wamp\www\wp\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 525

Comment: what are you trying to do? specified it ..!! you want to add menu in header ?

Comment: yes........................

Comment: you want to add menu and sub menu in admin panel ? or in front site. in header. php. please explain your problem in brief. and what you have try.

Answer (score 0):

ADD menu and sub-menu in word-press admin panel -> try this

```
function jmenu_plugin_top_menu(){
   add_menu_page('My Plugin', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', __FILE__, 'jmenu_render_plugin_page', plugins_url('/img/icon.png',__DIR__));
   add_submenu_page(__FILE__, 'Custom', 'Custom', 'manage_options', __FILE__.'/custom', 'jmenu_render_custom_page');
   add_submenu_page(__FILE__, 'About', 'About', 'manage_options', __FILE__.'/about', 'jmenu_render_about_page');
 }
 function jmenu_render_plugin_page(){
  ?>
   <div class='wrap'>
    <h2>plugin page</h2>
   </div>
  <?php
 }
 function jmenu_render_custom_page(){
   ?>
   <div class='wrap'>
    <h2>my sub page</h2>
   </div>
   <?php
 }
 function jmenu_render_about_page(){
   ?>
   <div class='wrap'>
    <h2>About my plugin page</h2>
   </div>
   <?php
 }

 add_action('admin_menu','jmenu_plugin_top_menu');
```

it will add menu and sub-menu in admin panel.

[image]

You can also refer this links for adding menu and submenu in admin panel.

http://clivern.com/adding-menus-and-submenus-for-wordpress-plugins/

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/